# align two divs side by side with floating (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive

how can I make this container responsive so the text and the img automatically become block elements. I tried it out with flex direction but for someway it doesnt work. Can someone correct my code if necessary and suggest me a media query rule for the responsive design

```
<div class="top">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="portrait">
       <img src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png" alt="">
       <h2>XXXXXXXXXX</h2>
    </div>
</div>

.top h1{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-grow: 1;
   background-color: black;
   height: 20vw;
   margin-top: 0;
   font-size: 5vw;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 5px 5px rgb(142, 135, 136);
}

.top img {
   width: 20vw;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: display: inline-block for the divs having id "text" and "img" in css;

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, so we can help you better!

Comment: @Aditya_kr that would not make it responsive!

Comment: What kind of responsive behavior are you expecting? Resizing? Disappearing? Wrapping?

Comment: for making it responsive use bootstrap grid system classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. `display: flex;` is very powerful property and useful when it comes to take up rest of the space and centering.

**Modification**
here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/47topxex/), I would not suggest this approach with using `max-width` as it's not "mobile-first". But if this is what you want for this project then ok.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

#text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: deeppink;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  } 

  #img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

#img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

#text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="img" src="https://www.archlinux.org/static/vector_tux.864e6cdcc23e.png" />
  <div id="text">text on the left, next to the img</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot man. It really helped me out. But one more thing. If I use this code you said and i wanna apply a media query rule for max-width 700px for example how can i change the items so they appear as block elements. so the text is above the img and both elements have 100% width?

Comment: it should be 100%. just as wide as the browser.

Comment: I have edited my question. I tried out flex-direction but it doesn't change anything. Could you take a look at my code please? thanks in advance

Comment: @lologic I'm not sure where you need `flex-direction` but is this something you looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/57uckf97/

Comment: @lologic just a hint though, it's better to style for classes then elements as in your case. You can check what I did on `portrait` :). Not sure what level you are on regarding css and html but if you really like to get nity grity with html and css you can check out BEM when you feel you are ready for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well so here it is if I understood well what you are trying to accomplish. Correct me or update your question if I am wrong!

```css
#img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}
#text{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img id="img" src="https://www.archlinux.org/static/vector_tux.864e6cdcc23e.png"/>
    <div id="text">text on the left, next to the img</div>
    
</div>
```